# Python linked list error code

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, linked-list

I have some problems with the code. It says that `str` has no attribute `top`.. The meaning of this program is to use linked list and whenever I try to put some values in `put` I get some errors..

```
class LinkedQ(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.top = None

    def __str__(self):
            s = ""
            p = self.first
            while p != None:
                s = s + str(p.value)
                p = p.next
            return s

    def put(self):
        ny = Node(x)
        ny.next = self.top
        self.top = ny

    def get(self):
        x = self.top.value
        self.top = self.top.next
        return x

    def isEmpty(self):
        if self.top == None: 
            return True
        else:
            return False

class Node:
   def __init__(self, x):
      self.value = x
      self.next = None

row = input("Write line of numbers (1 2 3 4): ")
row_pi = row.split()
for i in row_pi:
      LinkedQ.put(i)
```

Comment: Homework i called homework for the reason but at lest be so nice and provide full traceback.

Comment: Nope you don't get that error. Because you don't get that far...LinkedQ.put(i) --> TypeError: unbound method put() must be called with LinkedQ instance as first argument (got int instance instead)

Comment: @RobertCaspary: OP is clearly using Python 3 (and does get that error).

Comment: Iam using python 3.3.2

Comment: @Wooble: Sadly, because the error message from 2.7 is a clear indication for one of the problems :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your `put` method doesn't take an `x` parameter, but tries to use the local variable `x` within its body. Presumably, you mean to be using the value that you're passing to the method on the last line of your code, which means your method should have the signature:

```
def put(self, x):
```

However, there is another problem. You're trying to call the method on the **class**:

```
LinkedQ.put(i)
```

when it is an instance method. You need to instantiate an object of the class before you can call its instance methods:

```
some_linked_q = LinkedQ()
for i in row_pi:
    some_linked_q.put(i)
```

You have some other problems elsewhere, but this will at least fix the error you mention in the question. (Look for variables you're using that you don't define anywhere...)

Comment: +1; beat me to it. The only other problem I can find is in the `__str__` method: `self.first` should be `self.top` instead. Otherwise, it looks okay and seems to work fine.